# How do I display a JavaScript response in proper manner?

Tags: javascript, html, json

Below is my JavaScript code for calling the server API:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  call_juvlon_api(apikey, 'getAvailableCredits', '', function(response) {
     document.getElementById('show').innerHTML=response;
  });   
</script>
```

When I print the response in an HTML tag:

```
<h1 id='show'></h1>
```

I'm getting results in this format:

```
{"code":"200","status":"Success:Mail Credit Details","Mail Credits":"46"}
```

But what I want is a result like this:

```
<h1>code:200</h1>
<h1>status:Success:Mail Credit Details</h1>
<h1>Mail Credits:46</h1>
```

I tried the following, but nothing was displayed:

```
var obj=['show'] 

var tbl=$("<table/>").attr("id","mytable");
$("#div1").append(tbl);
for(var i=0;i<obj.length;i++)
{
    var tr="<tr>";
    var td1="<td>"+obj[i]["code"]+"</td>";
    var td2="<td>"+obj[i]["status"]+"</td>";
    var td3="<td>"+obj[i]["color"]+"</td></tr>";

    $("#mytable").append(tr+td1+td2+td3);
}
```

Comment: I had posted....what I had tried...take a look onit....!!!

Answer (score 0):

First of all you'll need 3 h1 elements, so change the 'show' element to a div like this;

```
<div id='show'></div>
```

Then in your javascript code, access response elements by their name like this;

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
   call_juvlon_api(apikey, 'getAvailableCredits', '', function(response) {
    var obj = JSON.parse(response);
    for(var prop in obj) {
       document.getElementById('show').innerHTML += '<h1>' + prop + ":" + obj[prop] + '</h1>';
    }
});
```

Comment: I had tried it....but its displaying same result i.e `{"code":"200","status":"Success:Mail Credit Details","Mail Credits":"46"}`

Comment: Are you sure that your call_juvlon_api function returns a valid JSON ?